# How to retrieve amazon order id associated with magento salesorder through Magento API?

Tags: php, magento

I am using following extension to retrieve my orders from amazon and rautken.com in magento 
and save them against magento salesorder

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebay-magento-integration-order-import-and-stock-level-synchronization-also-supports-amazon-rakuten-and-play-com.html

But now I want to retrieve associated amazon order id through magento soap api, but It is not returning my any information related to it

I am using salesorder.list and salesorder.info method but it's not working

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can find this information from the additional data section. You get it from the order object.

```
$order->getData('additional_data');
```

You can see this data is serialized and can retrieve the data by unserializing. The amazon order number is associated with "channel_order_id".
I haven't tried this, but hope this will help you.